# Video freezes at first when watching in Chrome on Apache's localhost

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, mp4, freeze

I am trying to play mp4 video files through Chrome.

When I view the mp4 video on the hard drive directly all is fine, but once the video is stored on Apache's localhost the mp4 video freezes at first and only becomes normal once I have forced a refresh through ctrl-f5. Now with the system I am setting up it is not possible to make the client force refresh on every video he needs to see.

How do I bypass needing to force refresh on mp4 videos when on Apache's localhost in Chrome?

My operating system is L-Ubuntu 14.04 and the browser is Chrome, version 34.0.1847.132.

I've tried setting the preload property to "none", but to no avail.

Comment: Try 1) F12 in webbrowser 2) go network tab 3) access url with video 4) wait freeze 5) after freeze go to network tab 6) analyze the video request

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the .htaccess file. I think it's the video preloading. If you are loading the video throught a  tag inside a html file, you should set the preload property to "none". 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp

Comment: I tried setting preload to "none" but to no avail. Question updated.

Comment: Also, the video fails without even being inside an html tag.

Comment: Did you try to open the file with another browser (for example Firefox)?

Comment: So the problem is not the Apache server. Try to:
1) Update to the latest version: it should be Chrome 35.
2) Disable all the Chome's plugins (if any).
3) Convert the video to another video format

Comment: I updated Chrome to version 35, disabled the only plugin that was effective and restarted the computer. Still freezes. I cant convert the video to another format for this system will work on videos whos format i dont have control over.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
//autoplay muted onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true"  

<video id="abc" autoplay muted onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" >
  <source src="https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement-files/blob/master/big_buck_bunny.mp4?raw=true" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```